# NullPointerException thrown while creating AccessibilityNodeInfo of TextView

Tags: android

I'm trying to create `AccessibilityNodeInfo` of `TextView` using following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

    userTexView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userTextView);
    userTexView.createAccessibilityNodeInfo();
}
```

activity_user.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/UserText"
    android:contentDescription="@string/UserDescription" />
```

But I'm getting NullPointerException.

```
05-20 07:15:14.383 29984 29984 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 07:15:14.383 29984 29984 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:5059)
05-20 07:15:14.383 29984 29984 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:5004)
05-20 07:15:14.383 29984 29984 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(TextView.java:8048)
05-20 07:15:14.383 29984 29984 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:4965)
05-20 07:15:14.383 29984 29984 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:4952)
05-20 07:15:14.383 29984 29984 E AndroidRuntime:    at in.mobilitas.mhealth.ui.MHealthActivity.onCreate(MHealthActivity.java:82)
05-20 07:15:14.383 29984 29984 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5150)
05-20 07:15:14.383 29984 29984 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-20 07:15:14.383 29984 29984 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2192)
05-20 07:15:14.383 29984 29984 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more
```

Has anybody faced similar issue?

Comment: Is that code in `onCreate` and is it after you've called `setContentView(R.layout.activity_user)`?

Comment: Thanks. I shouldn't have bothered with that comment anyway; it's clear from the stack trace that `userTextView` isn't `null`. Is this on an emulator or on a real device? What API level is running? (According to [this crash report and associated Bugzilla issue](https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/list?signature=java.lang.NullPointerException%3A%20at%20android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java)#tab-reports), some users of Firefox for Android are encountering the same problem.

Comment: @TedHopp I was creating AccessibilityNodeInfo before the View was attached to Window. See the accepted answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createAccessibilityNodeInfo()` cannot be called until the View has been attached to the window. See the source code for the View class:

```
void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
   Rect bounds = mAttachInfo.mTmpInvalRect;
```

The bounds of the current view are used to fill up the `AccessibilityNodeInfo` instance, and those are undefined before the view is attached.

Answer (score 1):

The accept answer is correct, I'm just adding one way to get around it:

in onCreate:

```
View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.my_view);
view.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
        // Do some stuff with info
    }
}
```